# SimpleDateFormat bug or misunderstanding pattern and lenient?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Having code:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d HH:mm yyyy");
```

This will work as expected with:

```
simpleDateFormat.parse("Mar 27 02:02 2016");
simpleDateFormat.parse("Mar 27 03:02 2016");
```

However             `simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);`

will make the parse("Mar 27 02:02 2016") fail.
This makes me totally confused - What I can see, The SDF-format pattern is correct right? So it shouldn't matter if lenient was set. Also, I tried a lot of other random (thousands) datestrings in the same format and it's only  "Mar 27 02:02 2016" datestring that fails -. What is going on here? 
Note, locale is sv_SE if that matters and timezone is "Europe/Stockholm" (and useDaylight for created calendar is true).

Comment: Are you in a Locale that had Daylight Saving Time (a.k.a. Summer Time) start on Sunday, March 27, 2016?

Comment: Ah, yes, actually I am - why would that make it fail though?

Comment: Where I am in the United States, when daylight savings time takes effect, we go directly from 1:59:59 to 3:00:00.  The 2:00 hour never existed.  Leniency for `SimpleDateFormat` means turning things like April 31 into May 1 and April 32 into May 2.

Comment: Thats kind of the right answer - the time mentioned doesn't exist, and thats why theres an exception. One workaround would be to setLenient(true) - the default - another to verify that time given isn't in the daylight saving zone before.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested as below and it worked fine for me

```
Locale locale = new Locale("sv", "SE");
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d HH:mm yyyy", locale);
simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
Date pDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("Mar 27 02:02 2016");
//simpleDateFormat.parse("Mar 27 03:02 2016");
System.out.println(pDate);
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed vital information in the query and did update it now, see query for timezone.

Comment: and try with that, then it should be reproducable for you too.

Comment: Yes, could reproduce it after setting the timezone which is due to the daylight saving. Setting the lenient as true escapes the check.

Comment: Yes, I understand now that the time given "02:02" doesn't exist in my zone because of the daylight saving (which did go from 02:00 to 03:00 and skipped the hour in between.